# Specman print reference to struct

Tags: specman

I have a very big struct.

Is it possible to print to the console only the reference to this struct so that it will be possible afterwards to click on it and browse it through "data browser" window?

Comment: Hi Alex, did you mean to print the handle of the struct with a message()\messagef() method?

Comment: Yes, I've tried using "print" and not "message", thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, for example, simply by using the `out()` routine. By default, it prints a struct exactly in the form that can later be clicked to open it in data browser. Or similarly with `message()` or any other similar routine.

In fact, this is what the default `to_string()` method returns for a struct. And `out()`, `message()`, etc. use `to_string()` to decide how to display each of their parameters.